# My Discord bot disconnect and go offline after 2 minutes after connecting to the voice channel?I need to change my bot nickname to current date

Tags: python, discord.py

My Discord bot disconnect and go offline after 2 minutes after connecting to the voice channel?I need to change my bot nickname to current date
My bot does not run on the server, it runs on my computer
sorry for my bad english

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from persiantools.jdatetime import JalaliDate, JalaliDateTime
import datetime


TOKEN = '-'
client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
        guild = client.get_guild(-)
        channel = guild.get_channel(-)
        await channel.connect()
        new_nick = str(JalaliDate.today())
        await guild.get_member(client.user.id).edit(nick = new_nick)
        await client.change_presence(activity = discord.Activity(type = discord.ActivityType.watching , name = 'Calendar ►►► Developed by Nex1x'))
        print(JalaliDateTime.today() ,'\n\nBot Online Shod XD\nDeveloped by Nex1x')
        while True:
                time = datetime.datetime.now()
                y = str(time.hour) + '-' + str(time.minute) + '-' + str(time.strftime("%p"))
                if y == '12-00-AM':
                        new_nick = str(JalaliDate.today())
                        await guild.get_member(client.user.id).edit(nick = new_nick)
                        await asyncio.sleep(60)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Show code, error messages, etc.

Comment: Does the voice channel have an auto-afk feature?

Comment: @KindStranger How do I find out?

Comment: I think this is a built-in feature of discord actually.  See this tweet from Discord https://twitter.com/discord/status/1096354824642269184?lang=en

Comment: You are changing your bot's nickname after your condition (`y=='12-00-AM'`)

Comment: @12944qwerty yes what should i do?

Comment: Did you want to change the bot's nickname? Who's nickname did you want to change?

Comment: @12944qwerty Bot nickname

Comment: Can you specify all of that in your question? Including what you want to change it to?

Comment: @12944qwerty Yes

Comment: You are already changing the nickname to the date, I'm assuming. What's going wrong there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231884/discussion-between-erfan-and-12944qwerty).

Comment: @KindStranger why Ryhtm music bots always be in voice channel if you have premium plan on it and enabled this feature  , no dissconnect from voices if doesnt playing any music? sry for my bad english